Deploy Jar to Remote Repo Maven
I am trying to build jackson-databind jar from source and then upload it to a remote repo using maven.
I have already added the repo credentials in setting.xml file and added repo in pom.xml of the project file.
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id> Same_as_setting.xml </id>
        <name> RepoName </name>
        <url> RepoURL </url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

Using this command for the task:
mvn clean deploy -DskipTests

Till the install task it working fine and the jar is getting created in the target folder but after that task its failing!!!
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.13:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy) on project jackson-databind: Execution injected-nexus-deploy of goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.13:deploy failed: Server credentials with ID "sonatype-nexus-staging" not found! -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.13:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy) on project jackson-databind: Execution injected-nexus-deploy of goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.13:deploy failed: Server credentials with ID "sonatype-nexus-staging" not found!

I am able not to figure if this is really required and if not how do I disable this task. I tried manually adding the plugin (as mentioned below) in pom.xml and disable it but didn't work.
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.13</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>injected-nexus-deploy</id>
       <phase>none</phase>
     </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>

Complete error stacktrace
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.13:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy) on project jackson-databind: Execution injected-nexus-deploy of goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.13:deploy failed: Server credentials with ID "sonatype-nexus-staging" not found! -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.13:deploy (injected-nexus-deploy) on project jackson-databind: Execution injected-nexus-deploy of goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.13:deploy failed: Server credentials with ID "sonatype-nexus-staging" not found!
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:904)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:281)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:204)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:314)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution injected-nexus-deploy of goal org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.13:deploy failed: Server credentials with ID "sonatype-nexus-staging" not found!
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:904)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:281)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:204)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:314)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Server credentials with ID "sonatype-nexus-staging" not found!
    at org.sonatype.nexus.maven.staging.remote.RemoteNexus.<init> (RemoteNexus.java:81)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.maven.staging.deploy.strategy.AbstractStagingDeployStrategy.createRemoteNexus (AbstractStagingDeployStrategy.java:58)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.maven.staging.deploy.strategy.StagingDeployStrategy.deployPerModule (StagingDeployStrategy.java:70)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.maven.staging.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:904)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:281)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:204)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:314)
[ERROR]

I don't have password for sonatype-nexus-staging, moreover I don't want to deploy to there.

You have to add an entry in your settings.xml for the appropriate id Server credentials with ID "sonatype-nexus-staging" not found check: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

This question is similar to: Sonatype Nexus: How to set a single server credentials for multiple repositories in maven's settings.xml?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@aled, Sorry if I wasn't clear but what I wanted to achieve is to deploy/upload the final jar to the repo I set with distributionManagement tag in pom.xml and I don't have credentials for sonatype-nexus-staging. I did the same thing with activeMQ jar and they didn't give me this error and got upload to repo.

Do you get the nexus staging plugin from a parent POM? Did you have a look at the effective POM?

Did you find an answer to this? I'm facing the same issue
